# Develop Xbox 360 Apps

Tags: xbox360

I have been asked to develop an Xbox 360 app. Not a game but an application like Netflix, Youtube or Muzu... I find it realy hard to find any information on app development for the Xbox console. Can anybody give me some advice?

I know that the XDK allows game development in native C++ but is it suitable for creating apps as well? Is there any information on the submission process and policies for Xbox 360 apps?

Comment: I am interested in this as well. Did you ever find dev info for xbox 360 apps?

Comment: Same here. Did you find a resource or someone to call about this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to ask the question,  "What's the difference between a game and an application?" I'm sure you could use XNA to build an application as well thus develop your app in C#, using the libraries Microsoft provides. Good luck!

Comment: You might be right. But I don't know - is there any difference between indie games and app(lications) on the xbox? As far as i understood XNA applications ("games") only have limited network capabilities on the console. Also they are published to the "indie games" section in the store (sry have no xbox here to look that up...) not among the other "apps" (Youtube ect...)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if what you want is possible with XNA. If you are registered xbox developer, you should talk to your developer account manager.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you may get detailed explanation from theese links

http://www.xbox.com/en-US/developers

http://www.xboxmb.com/forum/15-xbox-360-tutorials/67430-how-create-xbox360-applications-sdk.html